# Can't hide element with timeout (react, jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
addAlert () {



    this.refs.container.success(
      "Welcome welcome welcome!!",
      "You are now home my friend. Welcome home my friend.", {
      timeOut: 3000,
      extendedTimeOut: 11000,
      closeButton:true
    });
  //  $("#toast-container > div").hide(0).delay(5000).hide(0);
   setTimeout($('.searchBlock').fadeIn('slow'), 3000);

    //window.open("http://youtu.be/3SR75k7Oggg");
  }
```

Can't hide element with timeout
Get error: VM83256:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: You aren't passing anything to `setTimeout`.

Comment: please explain more detail

Comment: he is passing, but it should be a function (definition) or anonymous function, not an invoked function

Comment: `setTimeout` accepts a function.  You're passing whatever `fadeIn()` returns, which is not a function.

Comment: How to do correct way?

Answer (score 2):

The possible correction is to add anonymous function, change the following line:

```
 setTimeout(function(){
   $('.searchBlock').fadeIn('slow');
 },3000);
```

Comment: And how to paste it?